# AVAssetImageGenerator iOS 4.2.1 bug?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im trying to generate an image from an mp4 video but it will fail on iPhone iOS 4.2.1 with this error

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AVFoundationErrorDomain error -11800.)" UserInfo=0x140c00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x13e520 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12911.)"}

It works just fine on iOS 4.3.1 and simulator 4.2/4.1.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"evil" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
NSError *error = nil;
CGImageRef image = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:asset.duration actualTime:nil error:&error];
if(image == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the source very short? We had a problem with generating thumbnails when the movie's keyframe interval was longer than the movie itself -- there seems to be an issue with the `AVAssetImageGenerator` where it needs at least 2 keyframes to be present in the file to be able to generate an image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the file exists and that your program finds it?
Sometimes the files exists in your project bundle, but not in your folder.
you can try to copy the file in your folder again (overwrite it), and then drag it again in your resource folder in xcode. It worked for me for a similar problem.

Comment: That my first thought as well but the video does play when I load via AVURLAsset and assign that to AVPlayer. The bug appears to be specific with the image generator. I also tried .mov and an mp4 without an audio track just to see if it was something about the format.